# iptables - ruby on rails mailer problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iptables, ubuntu-12.04

Hey guys i am having issues with my iptables configuration. When i allow all packets my mailer in ruby works. When i deny all and have my rules setup i have issues sending mail.

The output from the syslog

```
Jun 21 20:00:41 JJD-PRODUCTION-WEBSITE kernel: [ 1450.576269] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC= DST= LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=40128 PROTO=TCP SPT=587 DPT=37296 WINDOW=14180 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Jun 21 20:00:41 JJD-PRODUCTION-WEBSITE kernel: [ 1450.979805] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC= DST= LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=40129 PROTO=TCP SPT=587 DPT=37296 WINDOW=14180 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Jun 21 20:00:42 JJD-PRODUCTION-WEBSITE kernel: [ 1451.574917] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC= DST= LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=40130 PROTO=TCP SPT=587 DPT=37296 WINDOW=14180 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Jun 21 20:00:42 JJD-PRODUCTION-WEBSITE kernel: [ 1451.579830] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC= DST= LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=40131 PROTO=TCP SPT=587 DPT=37296 WINDOW=14180 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Jun 21 20:00:43 JJD-PRODUCTION-WEBSITE kernel: [ 1452.779869] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC= DST= LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=40132 PROTO=TCP SPT=587 DPT=37296 WINDOW=14180 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

I have removed the source port, destination port and mac addresses/

Also here is my iptables -L output.

```
root@JJD-PRODUCTION-WEBSITE:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:https state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http limit: avg 25/min burst 100
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssmtp state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:https state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:submission state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssmtp state ESTABLISHED

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
root@JJD-PRODUCTION-WEBSITE:~#
```

anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

I made rules to allow both 587 and 465 both in and out

Comment: You've only got `state NEW` on `ssh` and `https` in `OUTPUT`. Is this intentional?

Comment: not that i know of, is that supposed to be with the other ports also?

Comment: Somehow the connection has to be established in the first place, right?

Comment: still does not seem to be working, makes sense what you are saying but doesn't want to work.

Comment: Hrm, only 14 views in 20 hours. I'll flag this for moderator attention to see if it can be migrated to [SF], they may be a better audience.

Answer (score 0):

- Your rules seem a bit messy, you have a bunch of rules after `ACCEPT anywhere`, which doesn't make sense.
- With this exact `iptables -L`, you allow all packets in and out, so I doubt your issues are related to firewalling. Please provide us with the output of `iptables -nvL` when E-mail delivery is broken (`-n` makes things more readable for network people, we admins like port numbers).